# HasMany: Empty list instead of null

Tags: castle-activerecord

I am using CastleProject ActiveRecord.
I have the following property in my class:

```
[HasMany(typeof(Order), Table = "Orders", ColumnKey = "OrderId")]
internal IList<Order> Orders
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

In case Orders table does not contain any orders, Orders property is null. Can I somehow point ActiveRecord that it should create empty list instead of returning null, without giving up autoproperty?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you want, but couldn't you instantiate an empty list in the constructor:

```
public MyClass()
{
  Orders = new List<Order>();
}
```